# ¿Por qué tengo este error?: (Not jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 Found)

Tags: php, ajax, mvc, razor

Necesito comprobar si el email ingresado por el usuario existe en la base de datos. Para esto estoy implementando `ajax` y `php,`. Con ajax le paso el email ingresado por el usuario a `validation.php` para que me devuelve una respuesta si existe o no el email. Pero cuando me fijo por consola, me marca este error: `POST http://localhost:52197/Usser/validation.php 404 (Not jquery-3.3.1.js:9600  Found).`
Aclaro que:

1. Tengo integrado en la carpeta Scripts el archivo `jquery-3.3.1.js`.

2.En la `view` donde con ajax paso el email a `validation.php` tengo declarado `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

¿Entonces por qué no encuentra el archivo jquery si lo tengo integrado?

Aca `Ajax`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#txtEmail').on('blur', function () {
        var email = $('#txtEmail').val();
        if (email == '') {
            email_state = false;
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validation.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'email_check': 1,
                'email': email,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'taken') {
                    email_state = false;
                    $('#txtEmail').parent().removeClass();
                    $('#txtEmail').parent().addClass("form_error");
                    $('#txtEmail').siblings("span").text('Sorry... Email already taken');
                } else if (response == 'not_taken') {
                    email_state = true;
                    $('#txtEmail').parent().removeClass();
                    $('#txtEmail').parent().addClass("form_success");
                    $('#txtEmail').siblings("span").text('Email available');
                }
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

aca `validation.php`

```html
<?php 
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'acaMicontraseña', 'libreria');

 if (isset($_POST['email_check'])) {
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email='$email'";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
     echo "taken"; 
   }else{
     echo 'not_taken';
   }
   exit();
  }
?>
```

Comment: `~/Scripts/jquery.js` parece ser la ruta a tu directorio home. Para tu webserver eso no significa nada. Sus rutas parten en `/` para el document root y de ahí hacia adentro

Comment: acabo de intentar con estas rutas:  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> tmb <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> y me sigue dando error. (Por las dudas aclaro que el localhost es el predeterminado de visualstudio)